# What file does my satchmo store welcome email come from?

Tags: django, email, satchmo

I am using satchmo store and when some one signs up right now it sends a welcome email. However I have no idea what file this welcome email comes from so i can edit the message.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in **satchmo_store/contact/templates/registration** folder. There should be a file **welcome.txt**.

All the registration related templates are present in that folder. Although I will highly recommend you **NOT** to edit the templates in the package itself, but rather override them with our own. Refer to [this](http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/dev/customization.html#template-customization) for details.